# Custom Viewhandler for JBoss 7.1

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I want to implement a custom ViewHandler. Currently I'm only forwarding all calls to the default Viewhandler, but if I enable this ViewHandler in my faces-config.xml, the preRenderView event type (and maybe other functionality) is broken. Does anybody no what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Thanks.

```
public class ReverseProxyViewHandler extends ViewHandler {

ViewHandler defaultHandler;

public ReverseProxyViewHandler(ViewHandler defaultHandler) {
    this.defaultHandler = defaultHandler;
}

@Override
public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext context) {
    return defaultHandler.calculateLocale(context);
}

@Override
public String calculateRenderKitId(FacesContext context) {
    return defaultHandler.calculateRenderKitId(context);
}

@Override
public UIViewRoot createView(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
    return defaultHandler.createView(context, viewId);
}

@Override
public String getActionURL(FacesContext context, String path) {
    return defaultHandler.getActionURL(context, path);
}

@Override
public String getResourceURL(FacesContext context, String path) {
    return defaultHandler.getResourceURL(context, path);
}

@Override
public void renderView(FacesContext context, UIViewRoot viewToRender) throws IOException, FacesException {
    defaultHandler.renderView(context, viewToRender);
}

@Override
public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
    return defaultHandler.restoreView(context, viewId);
}

@Override
public void writeState(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    defaultHandler.writeState(context);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but by extending the `ViewHandlerWrapper` instead of the the `ViewHandler` I got it to work.

Here is an example of my `CustomViewHandler` (not a complete example, but was built within our app as a proof of concept) :

```
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandler;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CustomViewHandler extends ViewHandlerWrapper {

    private ViewHandler wrapped;
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomViewHandler.class);
    
    public CustomViewHandler(ViewHandler wrapped) {
        LOGGER.info("CustomViewHandler.CustomViewHandler():wrapped View Handler:"+wrapped.getClass());
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
        UIViewRoot root;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("restoring view : " + viewId);
            root = wrapped.restoreView(context, viewId);
        } catch (ViewExpiredException e) {
            LOGGER.error("View Expired : " + e.getMessage() + " -> recreating");
            root = wrapped.createView(context, viewId);
        }
        return root;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ViewHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }
}
```

If you want a more complete and functional custom view handler, look at the `OmniFaces` [RestorableViewHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/enableRestorableView).  Source code is available on that page.

### From Java Doc

> #### javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper
>
> Provides a simple implementation of ViewHandler that can be subclassed by developers >wishing to provide specialized behavior to an existing ViewHandler instance. The default >implementation of all methods is to call through to the wrapped ViewHandler.
>
> Usage: extend this class and override getWrapped to return the instance we are wrapping.